# Generic method will not compile (c#)

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have some collections and methods like these:

```
public IEnumerable<UserRole> SystemUserRoles { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }

private bool CheckUserRoleNameForDoubling(UserRole userRole)
{
    var userRoles = SystemUserRoles.ToList();
    userRoles.Remove(userRole);
    
    return !userRoles.Select(p => p.Name).Contains(userRole.Name);
}

private bool CheckLoginForDoubling(User user)
{
    var userList = Users.ToList();
    userList.Remove(user);
    
    return !userList.Select(p => p.Login).Contains(user.Login);
}
```

I tried the code below, but it will even not compile.

```
private bool CheckFieldForDoubling<T>(T obj, IEnumerable<T> col, string field)
{
    var list = col.ToList();
    list.Remove(obj);

    return !list.Select(p => ((T)p)[field]).Contains(obj[field]);
}
```

How do I make generic method ?

**UPDATE1**
These methods are for the validation of the collection objects after adding or editing before storing them into DB.
The problem is with this string

```
return !list.Select(p => ((T)p)[field]).Contains(obj[field]);
```

It says "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'T'"

Comment: When it doesn't compile, do you get an error message? If so, what's the error code and the message? On what line does it appear? Don't leave us to guess.  And  separately, what's _"cols"_ mean here?

Comment: I suspect that it doesn't like `((T)p)[field]).Contains(obj[field])`. You haven't _constrained_, so the compiler is going to tell you that an object of type `T` doesn't support indexing. But, still, tell us what the error is

Comment: What is the desired purpose of `CheckFieldForDoubling<T>` method, please? Note that since `T` is an arbitrary type, say `int`, `col.ToList()`, `col[field]` can't be compiled

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I think it is "see if list contains objects with the same value of given field/property" like passing `Func<T, TPropertyValue> propertyAccessor` instead of `filedName` and checking count of values for that property for all objects (or all objects that are not the given one).

Comment: Cols means collections. The error is "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'T'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble you are having is `obj[field]` is not a valid syntax for accessing an arbitrary field/property. Other answers mentioned reflection, which is one way to do this. Another is to pass in an accessor lambda funciton:

```
    private bool CheckFieldForDoubling<TObject, TField>(TObject obj, IEnumerable<TObject> col, Func<TObject, TField> accessor)
    {
        var list = col.ToList();
        list.Remove(obj);

        return !list.Select(accessor).Contains(accessor(obj));
    }
```

You would call it like this:

```
CheckFieldForDoubling(user, Users, u => u.Login);
```

Comment: Obviously, for the real code you'd skip `ToList` call that only creates extra garbage and instead filter that object out with `col.Where(x => x!=obj).Select(....`

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov
With **col.Where(x => x!=obj).Select(....** it says Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TObject' and 'TObject'

Answer (score 0):

Techinally, you can solve the task with a help of *Reflection* (in order to address *arbitrary* field or property
by its *name*):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

...    

private static bool CheckFieldForDoubling<T>(T obj, 
                                             IEnumerable<T> items, 
                                             string field) {
  FieldInfo fi = typeof(T)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | 
               BindingFlags.Public | 
               BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == field);

  PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | 
                   BindingFlags.Public | 
                   BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Where(item => item.CanRead)
    .Where(item => item.GetIndexParameters().Length <= 0)
    .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == field);

  return !items
    .Where(item => !object.Equals(item, obj))
    .Where(item => fi == null || object.Equals(fi.GetValue(obj), fi.GetValue(item)))
    .Where(item => pi == null || object.Equals(pi.GetValue(obj), pi.GetValue(item)))
    .Any();
}
```

But do you really want it? Note that you can simplify `CheckLoginForDoubling` into

```
private bool CheckLoginForDoubling(User user) => Users
  .All(item => item != user || item.Login == user.Login);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indexer `[field]` is just a method on a class. You either need to make all instances of your `T` derive from some common base class with the indexer, for example,

```
public abstract class Indexer
{
    public abstract object this[string i] { get; set; }
}
```

or implement a common interface, say,

```
public interace IIndexer
{
    object this[string i] { get; set; }
}
```

and then change your method by constraining the type of `T`:

```
private bool CheckFieldForDoubling<T>(T obj, IEnumerable<T> col, string field)
    where T : Indexer
{
    var list = col.ToList();
    list.Remove(obj);

    return !list.Select(p => ((T)p)[field]).Contains(obj[field]);
}
```

Now if you already have a base class or interface with an indexer for all of your types of `T`, then use that as your generic constraint.

If you need further compile-time type checking you could make `Indexer` itself generic.

If none of that works, you can drop down to reflection as noted in [Dmitry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75539376/64348).